# Specify object with at least one known property in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there any way in Typescript to specify an object that can have many properties but I know only one of them in advance?

For example:

```
const object = {a: 10, b: "hello"}
```

I only know for sure that `a` comes in this object, `b` can be another thing (like `c`) or maybe it is not present in the object. I would like to know if there is any way to specify a type where only `a` is known and other properties are "discarded".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface MyType {
  a: number;
 [key: string]: any;
}

const obj1: MyType = { a: 5 };
const obj2: MyType = { a: 5, b: 3 };
const obj3: MyType = { a: 5, c: 3 };
```